# installation_problem oracle developer Suite

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms, failed-installation

Using paramFile: \vmware-host\Shared Folders\F\oracle\32\oracle developer suite\ds_windows_x86_101202_disk1\install\oraparam.ini

Checking installer requirements...

Checking operating system version: must be 5.0, 5.1 or 5.2.    Actual 6.2
                                      Failed <<<<

Exiting Oracle Universal Installer, log for this session can be found at C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs\installActions2016-07-18_04-38-42AM.log

Please press Enter to exit...

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing on Oracle 10g Developer Suite on Windows 8? There are two ways to get around it.

- Download a patch for Developer Suite that allows this.
- Secondly before running setup there is a file from which it checks the windows version, just include 6.2 in the allowed versions.

I would say first search for the patch.

Hope this helps